# Backup and Reset Windows VPS password

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, password, password-reset

We do have an option like "Password Reset disk" for desktops. I like to know is there any similar option available for Windows VPS other than contacting the service provider control panel?

I like to backup the password and in case of forgotten password, or changed by other users using administrator tools, I want to reset it to the old password.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Generally with a VPS you don't have access to the hypervisor layer, so you have to go through your provider's control panel to perform password resets if you're locked out of a system.

Comment: In my service provider case it's time consuming job. I want quick and handy solutions. Any sort of exporting and reusing anything?

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Our cloud customers can reset their system passwords with a single click in the portal.  Are you asking about resetting a password for a system that you are locked out of, or for a system that you still can log in to?